# Lambda trigger timing out with no errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to implement a "post confirmation" cognito trigger, which code is run in a lambda function. The lambda function is timing out every time, without giving any error messages in cloudwatch logs. This is the lambda post confirmation trigger code:

```
const {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand,
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider')

let cognitoClient = null

//Sets up the cognito client
if (!cognitoClient) {
    cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient()
}

async function handler(event, context) {
    const command = new AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand({
        UserAttributes: [
            {
                Name: 'custom:user_organizationId',
                Value: '1',
            },
        ],
        Username: event.userName,
        UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
    })

    try {
        await cognitoClient.send(command)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            `Error running post sign up confirmtion for ${event.userName}: ${error}`
        )
    }

    return event
}

exports.handler = handler
```

At first I assumed the issue was due to not having an IAM role with cognito admin policies, so I added a policy for the method in the default lambda IAM role. I confirmed that the policies are indeed associated with the trigger lambda running.

What can be the reason for this? I thought it might be network related (still do) but the lambda has identical IGW config as my lambdas running from my API gateway which run s3 client methods successfully.